# SQL How do I fill empty tables in a new database and make the connections and foreign keys align?

Tags: sql, database

I have a project to create a simple database for a made-up business. I need to create all the tables and all the connections between them and fill in the tables.

I was able to create tables pretty easily and setting up primary and foreign keys where I want the tables to connect, but now I need to fill the tables with customers/orders/products, etc.

How would I fill a table with foreign keys and other things if all my tables are empty?

Example of a table I don't understand how to fill (all 'ID's are numbers):

```
Create table Orderdetails(
    OrderDetailsID int Primary Key Identity(1,1),
    InvoiceID int Foreign Key Invoices(InvoiceID),
    Product int Foreign Key Products(ProductID),
    Quantity int not null,
    Price money not null
)
```

I've only managed to fill my Customers table because it has no foreign keys and doesn't rely on any other table. I'm new to SQL, I understand the code pretty well but I don't understand how to build a database. Please help!

Comment: When you create a foreign key,all you are doing is linking it to the primary key of other table,instead of thinking of to just insert data,think in terms of  that business you are using as a project

Comment: You must start with tables that have no Foreign Key. (If all tables have a Foreign key, there is a design problem.)  Requirements of relational databases dictate that no data can reside in a child table if there is no parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill up the dependent tables first and then the reference table data.

here you have created the orderDetails table which has foreign key of InvoiceId and ProductId.

In this perticilar case If you want to insert a new orderDetails.
1st: Your have to insert product details to the product table.
2nd: Invoice details to the invoice table.
3rd: Now you have both priduct as well as invoice id which you can use while inserting order details.

Then you are able to insert all the data quite easyly.